# Reload SVG from a button within the same svg?

Tags: animation, svg, reload

I have an SVG animation and I want to reload it from the beginning when finish. It is possible to do this from a button placed on the same svg animation?

Like

```
<g id="button" >

 <a xlink:href="window.location.href=window.location.href">   </a>
```

or something like that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the current time for animations back to 0 using the `<svg>` element [setCurrentTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement) function. That would be more efficient as it wouldn't reload the page again.

Comment: You can do that from the svg button? I will investigate. Thank you!